# if statement in Django template not working

Tags: python, django

I can't find out why this is not working.
It always goes to {% else %} block.
The text in machine_model is something like "Lidl - Food Market" or "Kaufland - Buy Here" or something other without those two words.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse


class MyName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MySide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class MyMachine(models.Model):
    date_delivery = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    machine_name = models.ForeignKey(MyName, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    machine_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    machine_serial = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='0')
    use_side = models.ForeignKey(MySide, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import MyMachine

class MyMachineListView(ListView):
    model = MyMachine
    template_name = 'site/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'machines'
    ordering = ['date_delivery']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        site_title = 'Home'
        context["site_title"] = site_title
        return context
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "site/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% for machine in machines %}
            <article class="media content-section">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ machine.date_delivery|date:"d.F Y" }} 
                        </small>  
                    </div>
                        <h2><a class="article-title" href="">{{ machine.machine_name }} - {{ machine.machine_serial }}</a></h2>

                        {% if 'Lidl' in machines.machine_model %}
                            <p class="article-content">{{ machine.use_side }} - Lidl</p>
                        {% elif 'Kaufland' in machines.machine_model %}
                            <p class="article-content">{{ machine.use_side }} - Kaufland</p>
                        {% else %}
                            <p class="article-content">{{ machine.use_side }} - {{ machine.machine_model}}</p>
                        {% endif %}

                </div>
            </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

everything else is working fine. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here.

One, you're referencing `machines.machine_model`, but `machines` is a queryset. I'm somewhat surprised referencing `machine_model` on it doesn't just fail with a rendering error. It should be `machine.machine_model`, since that's your loop variable.

That leads us to the second problem. `machine.machine_model` is a foreign key reference to another model, not a string. There's no string that's `in` a model instance (barring defining the membership function yourself). I haven't personally tested but I don't think Django stringifies on the fly (as it will when you reference `{{ machine.machine_model }}`). Try it with `if ... in machine.machine_model.name`.

Comment: machines left from trying different options....originally was machine. I didn't know what to try more. And  `.name` works. Thanks @PeterDeGlopper